# Database-wide search in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a big database with +100 collections and one of them stores documents with the key `needle: “here”`. How can I find all `needle`s?

Something like `db.find({ needle: “here" })`? If not possible. How can I achieve the same in *a fast way*?

Answer (score 0):

there's no other way than iterating over the collections and issuing a find query per collection

```
var found = [];

db.getCollectionNames().forEach((coll) => {
    found.push(
        db.getCollection(coll)
            .findOne(
                {
                    needle: "here"
                }))
})

print(found.filter(x => x != null));
```